# clickedButtonAtIndex: ERROR

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have this code:

//SHOW ALERT

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Actualizado" 
message:@"Se ha actualizado todo" delegate:self 
cancelButtonTitle:@"Aceptar" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
```

and this

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert 
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"ALgo"); }
```

and got the following error:

```
 -[__NSCFType alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:]:
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdc559a0
```

Help please. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you might be releasing the object or view that handles the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` selector (the delegate). Make sure you keep it until your `UIAlertView` has been dealt with.

Comment: sorry the question but how can make sure that i keep the selector until it has been dealt with? I'm new in xcode

Comment: I can't tell you exactly what without looking at your code, but for example if you are in a `UIViewController`, don't call selectors such as `popViewControllerAnimated:` or `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` (if in a modal view controller) right after `[alert show]`; instead call them in `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`.

Comment: Ok you are correct @Juan, because if I do this without call any view, works fine. 
I used a function in other class or .m file and i call it this: `SWModificaciones *viewModificaciones = [[SWModificaciones alloc]init]` (SWModificaciones = .h) and use it this: `[viewModificaciones ejecutarModificacionesParaIpad:strTotalCambios];`(this work fine) after this I call the `UIAlertView` and then the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`. I not sure that how use other UIView in this class. Thanks. EXCUSE my English

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]  initWithTitle:@"Actualizado" message:@"Se ha actualizado todo" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Aceptar" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

have you added the UIAlertViewDelegate to your header file?
e.g
@interface yourclass: UIViewController
check if this may be the reason

Answer (score 0):

If your alertView is created inside a object instantiated from a ViewController, you need to keep a pointer to that object in the ViewController.